# Spring boot jpa select using multiple key values from joined map

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have the following working query which selects based on the key and value of a joined map.

```
@Query("select e from Entity e join e.dataAttributes da where " +
        "(key(da) =:attrKey1 and :attrVal1 in (value(da)) )")
List<Entity> findByAttrributeValues(@Param("attrKey1") String attrKey1,
                                      @Param("attrVal1") String attrVal1);
```

I would like to select based on 2 keys and 2 values, but am having difficulties. The following likely very naiieve attempt returns no results:

```
 @Query("select e from Entity e join e.dataAttributes da where " +
        "(key(da) =:attrKey1 and :attrVal1 in (value(da)) ) and " +
        "(key(da) =:attrKey2 and :attrVal2 in (value(da)) )")
List<Entity> findByTwoAttrributeValues(@Param("attrKey1") String attrKey1,
                                      @Param("attrVal1") String attrVal1,
                                      @Param("attrKey2") String attrKey2,
                                      @Param("attrVal2") String attrVal2);
```

I'm new to JPA, any guidence would be appreciated

Comment: most likely you just need to put and `or` instead of an `and` between the two sets of key and value.

Comment: Using or will not be semantically the same as and right? As in, OR would return results as specific as the first query in the OP rather than the more specific results using both key/value pairs

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with ":attrVal1 in (value(da)) )" ?? Makes no sense. "IN" when taking a single value would expect a Collection or subquery on the RHS

Comment: da in this instance is a collection an Map<String,String>. value(da) is querying the available values in the map no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have this solution :

```
@Query("select e from Entity e join e.dataAttributes da join e.dataAttributes da2 where " +
    "(key(da) =:attrKey1 and :attrVal1 in (value(da)) ) and " +
    "(key(da2) =:attrKey2 and :attrVal2 in (value(da2)) )")
List<Entity> findByTwoAttrributeValues(@Param("attrKey1") String attrKey1,
                                  @Param("attrVal1") String attrVal1,
                                  @Param("attrKey2") String attrKey2,
                                  @Param("attrVal2") String attrVal2);
```

I needed to join again onto the dataAttributes with a second identifier.  Works as expected now. Might not be the prettiest. If there's a better way let me know